# The uses of splitting square into triangle in texture mapping

Tags: texture-mapping

I know this question is simple for many people, but i'm just getting started in **texture mapping**. I have read many document and i still quite don't understand about it.

May i ask what is the **purpose of splitting an object in to triangles** with texture mapping ?

Does it use to **change the form and shape** of orginal object ?

Does is use to make an object (an image for example) **become more clearly** ?

If it is not use for making an object become more clearly, which technical of texture mapping use for making an object more clearly ?

Please undertand and correct me if i'm wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Triangles are the simplest planar shapes. For a triangle, the three vertices unambiguously define a plane. A square has four vertices, and three of those form a planar triangle, but the fourth one could lie outside the plane of the other three. That would form a non-planar shape. Mapping a texture onto such a shape would either require much more complex transformations, or it would lead to artifacts when assuming all vertices are on the same plane.

Thus, in order to simplify 3D calculations and to not having to assume that all vertices of squares (or polygons in general) are on the same plane, 3D generally uses triangles as the basic shape. That's not just for texture mapping, but for all 3D calculation and rendering purposes.